# How to find difference in yearweek and display in another column

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT COUNT(transaction.id) AS transactionCount, 
       YEARWEEK(transaction.orderdate) AS orderDate, 
       YEARWEEK(user.created_on) AS userJoinDate, 
       "difference in weeks", 
       user.fullname
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN user ON transaction.id_user = user.id
WHERE transaction.completed IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY user.id, 
      orderDate
ORDER BY userJoinDate ASC, 
      `user`.`fullname` ASC, 
      orderDate ASC
```

I only want to get the difference in weeks against the userJoinDate displayed.

Comment: It keeps on saying " Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column"

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of weeks between when a user joined and when they placed an order? (If so, the difference in `yearweek` won't give you that if the two dates are in different years)

Comment: That is correct @Pascal Bugnion. I'm trying to determine the difference in weeks from the time they joined.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need the difference in weeks then you'd use [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff). Remember that it calculates the difference in complete units (i.e. it performs FLOOR, not ROUND). So if you need in ROUNDing then add a half of week (i.e. add 7*24/2=84 hours interval) to 3rd argument.
2. All columns not used as aggregate function arguments (mentioned in output list, HAVING, ORDER BY, window functions) must be included into GROUP BY expression. The output columns may be referred by their position in both GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(transaction.id) AS transactionCount, 
       YEARWEEK(transaction.orderdate) AS orderDate, 
       YEARWEEK(user.created_on) AS userJoinDate, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, user.created_on, transaction.orderdate) difference_in_weeks, 
       user.fullname
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN user ON transaction.id_user = user.id
WHERE transaction.completed IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY 2, 3, 4, 5   -- output columns numbers
ORDER BY 3, 5, 2
```